# Angular2 and electron accessing browserWindwow object

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I am using Angular2 with Electron and WebPack.

I am trying to get a hold to the `BrowserWindow` object https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

I am doing on the top of my component

```
import * as electron from 'electron';
```

However when doing :

```
this.authWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false});
```

I get an error on runtime

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: electron.BrowserWindow is not a function

When logging electron itself looks like just a function so there is no `BrowserWindow` object in it.

```
function defineProgram(name, opts) {
  var program = new Program(name, opts);
  return program;
}
```

In WebPack I am using `webpackTargetElectronRenderer` to target Electron.

The intention is to open a new browser window object much like done here http://manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/

Comment: What is `remote.` for?

Comment: Sorry its not remote. Its

this.authWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between the renderer process and the main process, you need to use the `Remote` API (https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md).

Something like this should work:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;

this.authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked fine. I had already tried this but since I had the dependency of electron and also electron-prebuilt it was not working. Having just electron-prebuilt as dependency and doing the above worked nicelly;)

Thank you!